# How to differentiate between Varargs v/s Array type in Java

Tags: java, reflection

I am using reflection to create dynamic examples for my functions written under one class.

i.e below are my functions :

```
public void doSomething(int... args)
{
...
}
// Example to generate : doSomething(1,2,3,4,5);

public void doSomething2(int[] argsAsArray)
{
...
}
// Example to generate : doSomething2(new int[]{1,2,3,4,5})
```

My problem is, I am not able to differentiate between the types of **Variable args** v/s **Array** type of argument.

Is there a way that using which I can determine whether parameter type is **Variable args** or an **Array** ?

Comment: I believe they are the same type (array) passed

Comment: It is known as `Vararg` not `Variable length`. I was wondering, what are you asking until I see your code

Comment: Thanks @Ravi for heads up. I have updated my question accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (Method m : YourClass.class.getDeclaredMethods()) {
    System.out.println(m.getName() + "  varargs?  " + m.isVarArgs());
}
```

Comment: Thanks @sanit, you made my day :)